# Powershell split functionality for block data

Tags: powershell

I have an output in powershell like below:

```
Server Name: xx1
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 1000
Description: HHH

Server Name: xx2
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 10001
Description: HHH

Server Name: xx3
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 10003
Description: HHH
```

I want to split above output and store each block in a variable like

```
$x = Server Name: xx1
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 1000
Description: HHH
```

How can I do this using powershell?

Comment: What generated this output? Chances are you can just store the command output in a variable and just reference the index you want. For example, `$x = command`. Then `$x[0]` would be the data you want. Then you can simply do `$a = $x[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = ((The Command Here)  | Out-String) -split "\r\n"
$I = 0
@("Variable1","Variable2","Variable3") | Foreach {
  Set-Variable -Name "$_" -Value "$output[$I]"
  $I++
}
```

You can also use an array:

```
$x = The command
$x[0] # first line
$x[1] #second line
```

Comment: can you put above example in it? I tried but not working. Also the output is not confirm that it comes only 3. It may be 5,7 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If this output you have is a **single multiline** string, you can split on the empty newlines to get an array of textblocks you can use by their index number.

```
# here, your output is faked by a using a Here-String
$output = @'
Server Name: xx1
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 1000
Description: HHH

Server Name: xx2
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 10001
Description: HHH

Server Name: xx3
State: Running
Enabled: Enabled
Host Name: abc
PID: 10003
Description: HHH
'@

$items = $output -split '(\r?\n){2,}'
```

In this example you will have an array of 3 elements, you can use separately:

```
$x = $items[0]
$y = $items[1]
$z = $items[2]
```

or use a loop:

```
$items | ForEach-Object {
    # '$_' in here is a single element of the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a PowerShell command generated this output, you can simply store the output (default stdout results) in a variable. Each block of data will be an object with `property:value` pairs. The total output will be a collection of those objects. You can access each object using array indexing or conditional logic.

```
# Array Indexing
$x = command
$x[0] # First object
$a = $x[0] # Storing first object in a variable

# Conditional Logic
$x = command
$a = $x | Where {$_.'Server Name' -eq 'xx1'}

# Using Select-Object
$x = command
$a = $x | Select-Object -First 1
```

If the output is a single string, you will need to do some string manipulation. You can split the output into an array of strings. With strings as opposed to non-scalar objects, you won't have the `property:value` pairs, and therefore lose a lot of flexibility.

```
# $data is single string of your output
$x = $data -split '\r?\n\s*\r?\n' # split string
$a = $x[0] # Access first output block with index [0] and store in variable

# Store each server block in a variable: $a0, $a1, $a2, etc.
0..($x.Count-1) | Foreach-Object { 
    Set-Variable -Name a$_ -Value $x[$_]
}
$a0 # First server
$a1 # second server
$a2 # third server
```

If your output is an array of lines, you can loop through the array and create your own array of server items:

```
# Output is an array of strings
$x = command
$a = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $x.count; $i+=7) {
    ,$x[$i..($i+5)]
}
$a[0] # Your first array with xx1 data

# Store each server block in a variable: $b0, $b1, $b2, etc.
0..($a.Count-1) | Foreach-Object { 
    Set-Variable -Name b$_ -Value $a[$_]
}
$b0 # First server
$b1 # second server
$b2 # third server
```

If you intend to read your output from a file, you can choose to read the file as an array of strings or a single string. Then you can apply any of the above methods based on what you choose:

```
# Single String Read
$x = Get-Content file.txt -Raw

# Array of Strings Read
$x = Get-Content file.txt
```